# ModX Evo Wayfinder: Show 1st and 3rd level reources, but not 2nd?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I am using WayFinder to show particular resources with '&includeDocs'. EG:

`[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0`&level=`0`&includeDocs=`1,3`]]`

However, this wont show resources whose parents arent in that list, eg:

```
<ul>
<li>Level 1 - ID1: Show me
  <ul>
   <li>Level 2 - ID2: Skip me
       <ul>
         <li>Level 3 - ID3: Show me</li>
        <ul>
     </ul></li>
  </ul></li>
<ul>
```

So in this example, even though Ive specified I want to show resources 1 and 3, 3 will not show unless I show 2 as well.

Would anyone know how to fix this or if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
&parentRowTpl=`parentRow`
```

and `ParentRow` chunk must be:

```
[[+wf.wrapper]]
```